# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to make a discord bot which acts based on reactions, heres the code:

```
import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import random
    pershealth=50
    enhealth=75
    client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("fighting"))
        print("Works")
    @client.command()
    async def fight(ctx):
        options=["no","yes"]
        choice=random.choice(options)
        if(choice=="no"):
            await ctx.send("no monsters where found")
        else:
            msg=await ctx.send("Monster found, do you wanna fight it?")
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44D")
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44E")
            @client.event
            async def on_reaction_add(reaction,message):
                if reaction.emoji=="":
                    channel=message.channel.id
                    msg=await channel.send("test")
    client.run("code")
```

but when i run it it shows the error code AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'channel'. How to fix it?

Comment: can you correct the formatting of this code? Is the `on_reaction_add` event inside the fight command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `on_reaction_add` is not `message`. It's `user`.  I think what you want is

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji=="":
        channel=reaction.message.channel.id
        msg=await channel.send("test")
```

Honestly, I've never even used Discord module, and don't know anything about it. I just looked at the docs for the only function where you were trying to get a `channel` from the argument. Then I kept clicking the chain of members in `reaction` til it became apparent that `reaction.message.channel` exists. I'm telling you this because you could do that, too. Basically, I gave you a fish and also trying to teach you how to fish.

Comment: Fatherly tutored, the proverb could ".. feed him for a lifetime"️ ... if he learned [how to interpret the signal __AttributeError__](https://www.pythonpool.com/attribute-error-python/) & how the message hints for what to search`'<TYPE>' object has no attribute '<NAME>'`